# cada vez que salgo y entro a un fragment con un recyclerview se carga de nuevo la lista en el recyclerview y se duplican los datos?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, recyclerview

Estoy haciendo un reproductor de musica que tiene 3 pantallas/fragments y cada uno de estos fragments tiene su viewmodel.

El segundo fragment es el que muestra todas las canciones que hay almacenadas en el dispositivo, por lo que este tiene un recyclerview donde se carga la lista de todas las canciones. Toda esta logica, es decir, traer los datos y cargarlos en el recyclerview se realiza en el viewmodel de este fragment.

La llamada al metodo para que traiga la lista y la cargue en el recyclerview se lleva a cabo en el metodo "onCreateView" del fragment. Y aqui viene el problema... Cada vez que salgo y entro a este fragment se carga de nuevo la lista en el recyclerview y se duplica. Esto ocurre cada vez que entro y salgo del fragment, por lo que la lista siempre esta añadiendo nuevas canciones duplicadas y se vuelve infinito.

No entiendo muy bien porque ocurre esto, he estado investigando sobre los ciclos de vida y he realizado todo tipo de cambios en el codigo, pero siempre consigo el mismo resultado.

Como suelo decir, espero que no sea un fallo tonto jeje...

SongListFragment->

```
class SongListFragment : Fragment(), SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private lateinit var songsListViewModel: SongListViewModel
    private lateinit var rootView: View


    override fun <I : Any?, O : Any?> registerForActivityResult(
            contract: ActivityResultContract<I, O>,
            callback: ActivityResultCallback<O>
    ): ActivityResultLauncher<I> {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun <I : Any?, O : Any?> registerForActivityResult(
            contract: ActivityResultContract<I, O>,
            registry: ActivityResultRegistry,
            callback: ActivityResultCallback<O>
    ): ActivityResultLauncher<I> {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        Log.d("onCreateView", "onCreateView")
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_songlist, container, false)

        init()

        (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.setSupportActionBar(rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
        return rootView
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
    }


    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }


    private fun init(){
        songsListViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SongListViewModel::class.java)
        songsListViewModel.SongListViewModel(rootView, this)
        songsListViewModel.showAllDeviceSongs()

    }


}
```

SongListViewModel->

```
class SongListViewModel() : ViewModel() {

    private lateinit var view: View
    private lateinit var lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner

    private var listSongs = MutableLiveData<List<Song>>()
    private lateinit var adapter: CustomAdapteSongList

    fun SongListViewModel(root: View, lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner) {
        view = root

        adapter = CustomAdapteSongList(view.context, lifecycleOwner, R.layout.custom_card_song)
        setAdapter()

        this.lifecycleOwner = lifecycleOwner
    }

    fun showAllDeviceSongs(){
        setSongs()
    }

    fun setAllDeviceSongs(listSongs: List<Song>) {
        this.listSongs.value = listSongs
    }

    fun getSongsList(): LiveData<List<Song>> {
        return listSongs
    }

    private fun getAllDeviceSongs(): MutableLiveData<List<Song>> {
        var songList = MutableLiveData<List<Song>>()
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            songList.value = LocalSongsProvider.getAllDeviceSongs(view.context)
        }
        return songList
    }

    private fun setAdapter() {
        view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_deviceSongs).layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(view.context)
        view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_deviceSongs).adapter = adapter
    }

    private fun setSongs() {
        getAllDeviceSongs().observe(lifecycleOwner, Observer { it ->
            it?.let {
                adapter.setSongs(it)
            }
        })
    }


}
```

CustomAdapter->

```
class CustomAdapteSongList(
        val context: Context,
        val lifecycle: LifecycleOwner,
        val layout: Int,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapteSongList.ViewHolder>() {

    private var ListSongs: List<Song> = emptyList()


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val viewlayout = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(viewlayout, context)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val itemsong = ListSongs[position]

        holder.bind(itemsong, lifecycle)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return ListSongs.size
    }

    internal fun setSongs(songs: List<Song>) {
        this.ListSongs = songs
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class ViewHolder(viewlayout: View, val context: Context) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewlayout) {

        fun bind(dataitem: Song, lifecycle: LifecycleOwner) {
            // itemview es el item de diseño
            // al que hay que poner los datos del objeto dataItem
            itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title_song).text = dataitem.title
            itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.artist_name).text = dataitem.artistName

            var song_artWork = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart")
            song_artWork = ContentUris.withAppendedId(song_artWork, dataitem.id)


            val file = File(song_artWork.getPath())
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(file)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_standard_image_song)
                    .into(itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_image_song))

            itemView.tag = dataitem
        }
    }
}
```

LocalSongsProvider->

```
object LocalSongsProvider {

    private val allDeviceSongs = ArrayList<Song>()

    val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TRACK,
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.YEAR,
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST_ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST,
    )



    private fun getSongs(cursor: Cursor?): List<Song> {
        if (cursor != null) {
            // Cache column indices.
            val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)
            val titleColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)
            val trackColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK)
            val yearColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR)
            val durationColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION)
            val albumColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM)
            val artistIdColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID)
            val artistColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                // Get values of columns for a given video.
                val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
                val title = cursor.getString(titleColumn)
                val track = cursor.getInt(trackColumn)
                val year = cursor.getInt(yearColumn)
                val duration = cursor.getInt(durationColumn)
                val album = cursor.getString(albumColumn)
                val artistId = cursor.getInt(artistIdColumn)
                val artist = cursor.getString(artistColumn)

                val contentUri: Uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        id
                )

                // Stores column values and the contentUri in a local object
                // that represents the media file.
                allDeviceSongs.add(Song(id, contentUri, title, track, year, duration, album, artistId, artist))
            }
        }
        return allDeviceSongs.reversed()
    }


        fun getAllDeviceSongs(context: Context): List<Song> {
            val cursor = BuildSongCursor(context)
            Log.d("lista", getSongs(cursor).toString())
            return getSongs(cursor)
        }


        private fun BuildSongCursor(context: Context): Cursor? {
            try {
                return context.contentResolver.query(
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        projection,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null)
            } catch (e: SecurityException) {
                return null
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Vaya! Hay varias cosas para mejorar pero lo único que podría explicar el problema que describes es que el método `setSongs` del adapter en realidad sea un "addSongs", es decir que agregue los nuevos elementos a una lista ya existente y que se esté disparando dos veces debido al cache del liveData que innecesariame estás usando. Para que podamos ayudarte más debes mostrar el adapter y también el método `LocalSongsProvider.getAllDeviceSongs`

Comment: Ya he añadido el adapter y el objeto LocalSongsProvider. Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en el `LocalSongsProvider`. El método `getSongs` siempre retorna la propiedad `allDeviceSongs` agregandole nuevos valorers sin eliminar los anteriores

```
object LocalSongsProvider {
    private val allDeviceSongs = ArrayList<Song>()
    
    // este método duplica la lista
    private fun getSongs(cursor: Cursor?): List<Song> {
        while (...) {
            allDeviceSongs.add(...)
        }
        return allDeviceSongs.reversed()
    }
}
```

La solución es limpiar la lista antes de agregarle nuevos valores o bien convertirla en una variable local dentro de `getSongs`

```
object LocalSongsProvider {
    private fun getSongs(cursor: Cursor?): List<Song> {
        val allDeviceSongs = mutableListOf<Song>()
        while (...) {
            allDeviceSongs.add(...)
        }
        return allDeviceSongs.reversed()
    }
}
```

De cualquier forma deberías mejorar tu arquitectura. Probablemente `LocalSongsProvider` no debería ser un `object` sino una dependencia inyectable en `SongListViewModel`. Además le estás asignando al viewModel responsabilidades que no le corresponden. Cosas como crear un adapter deberían estar en el fragment. El viewModel debe contener la lógica de presentación pero no puede almacenar referencias a elementos del layout porque eso da lugar a bugs. Como está tu código ahora es muy dificil hacer testing aunque puedo imaginar que no los estás haciendo. También se nota que es tu primer día usando Kotlin así que como último tip te recomiendo el pathway [Kotlin for Java developers](https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/kotlin-for-java) y también la documentación sobre [Getters and setters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#getters-and-setters)