# Items duplicados con MvvM en Recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview, revisión-de-código, mvvm

No entiendo que estoy haciendo mal con mi Repository o con mi `ImageViewModel`, pero cuando cargo las imagenes de mi API, si voy a otra actividad y luego vuelvo, los `items` de mi `Recyclerview` se duplican.
Se que se ha respondido mil veces este problema, y he buscado demasiado, en muchos lados, entiendo hay distintas formas, pero no logro entender lo que esta mal en mi código.

```
class ImageViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val mutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<MyUri>
    private var repository: Repository? = null
    private var images: MutableLiveData<List<MyUri>>? = null
    fun init() {
        if (images == null) {
            repository = Repository.instance
            images = repository!!.fetchImages()
        }
    }

    fun getImages(): MutableLiveData<List<MyUri>>? {
        return images
    }

    init {
        mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData()
        getImages()
    }

}
```

```
class Repository private constructor() {
    private var listUri: ArrayList<MyUri> = ArrayList<MyUri>()
    private val images: MutableLiveData<List<MyUri>> = MutableLiveData<List<MyUri>>()

    fun fetchImages(): MutableLiveData<List<MyUri>>{
        val url = "https://m.monoe.de/cbc/a/309956328"
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        println(request)
        val client = OkHttpClient()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object :  okhttp3.Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: okhttp3.Call, response: okhttp3.Response) {
                val bodyJson = response.body?.string()

                val jsonData: String = bodyJson.toString()
                val Jobject = JSONObject(jsonData)
                val Jarray = Jobject.getJSONArray("images")

                val limit : Int = Jarray.length()

                for (i in 0 until limit) {
                    val `object` = Jarray.getJSONObject(i)

                    var data = MyUri("https://" + `object`.getString("uri"))

                    listUri!!.add(data)
                    images.postValue(listUri)
                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: okhttp3.Call, e: IOException) {
                println("Failed to execute request")
                e?.printStackTrace()
            }
        })
        return images
    }
    companion object {
        var instance: Repository? = null
            get() {
                if (field == null) {
                    field = Repository()
                }
                return field
            }
            private set
    }
}
```

Comment: te sirve [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/446882/198326) respuesta?

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem gracias por tu tiempo y responder, realmente necesito ayuda.

tengo en claro que puedo limpiar la lista, pero nose como hacerlo en este contexto y con este codigo..por eso sigo sin poder solucionar el problem.. algun ejemplo de como poder hacerlo?  de como limpiar la lista..?

Comment: Sería mejor que movieras la declaración de la variable `listUri` dentro del método `fetchImages`, ya que no la necesitas fuera de él. Eso debería solucionar el problema. En el link tienes un ejemplo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [cada vez que salgo y entro a un fragment con un recyclerview se carga de nuevo la lista en el recyclerview y se duplican los datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/446882/cada-vez-que-salgo-y-entro-a-un-fragment-con-un-recyclerview-se-carga-de-nuevo-l)

Comment: justo estaba viendo el ejemplo, ya lo estoy por intentar...luego te comento como me fue @SinneroftheSystem :)

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem man! lo hice funcionar..muchisimas gracias!, realmente hice ...literal" lo que sugeriste !!! me gustaria darte thumbs up! :)

Comment: Si te sirvió el enlace, puedes votar la pregunta y respuesta

Comment: ahi lo hice  :) @SinneroftheSystem gracias por hacerme pensar porque eso es lo mas importante... de las dos opciones la mas acorde es trabajar en la logica..
porque si limpio la lista.. es como que no usara un MvvM... logras lo que queres, pero no tiene sentido...me hiciste pensar...no sufriendolo..pero aprendiendo mas! de verdad gracias!

Comment: Genial! Aunque me refereía a votar la respuesta del enlace, no el comentario

Comment: ahah ahora lo hago!!! perdon @SinneroftheSystem